# consuming WCF method via web service getting error only in IIS not in IDE

Tags: wcf, web-services

I have added http://ws.hipcricket.com/api/EndUser.svc  as a service reference in a my web service. I am able to consume the methods from the IDE but while hosting the same in IIS I'm getting the following errors:

Error 1:

> Could not connect to the (please refer the above url). TCP error code 10060: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 69.20.116.221:80.

Error 2:

> There was no endpoint listening at (please refer the above url) that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See Inner Exception, if present, for more details

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have a firewall blocking communication from your webserver? When developing on your local machine communications through the proxy may most likely be using your credentials, while the user that the application pool that your application is running under on your IIS server most probably does not have the correct rights.